# Extract all fields with aliases from select / view statement using REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, select, field, aliases

How would I retrieve the fields from this sql statement?

```
create view CCV_REALPROP as select *, SUBSTRING( PARCEL_NO, 1, 3) as CC_GROUP from REALPROP
```

I need to retrieve the fields as such:

1: `*`

2: `SUBSTRING( PARCEL_NO, 1, 3) as CC_GROUP`

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you are trying to parse the SQL View as a string to get a list of all its fields/columns? If yes, then it seems awfully impractical way of doing it.

Comment: yes thats what im doing. do you know of a better way?

Comment: Well, if I wanted to get a list of columns for a specific view, I'd jump into SQL Developer (or any other SQL ide) and look at the View's schema directly. Or execute a desc (name of command depends on the db you use) query, e.g. `desc CCV_REALPROP`

Comment: are you able to retrieve the "SUBSTRING( PARCEL_NO, 1, 3)" part of it from desc?

Comment: Ok, I see, you're right, you would see only column names with the desc query.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't powerful enough to do this in the general sense. Recall that a column definition may itself be an arbitrarily complex (scalar) `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex is not powerful enough to do this.** [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245071/extract-all-fields-with-aliases-from-select-view-statement-using-regex#comment58208513_35245071) makes the excellent point that `SELECT` statements can have arbitrarily complex nested `SELECT` statements within themselves; even for your example, though, it's not feasible to properly parse the input. You're splitting on commas, but `SUBSTRING( PARCEL_NO, 1, 3)` itself has commas within it, breaking any regex that's not quite convoluted.

Depending on the language you're using, there's a variety of options you can take that aren't as complicated as regex; several languages have built in SQL parsers.